# How to dynamically pass the parameter to an Oracle Update Procedure?

Tags: c#, oracle, procedure

I have got several update stored procedures for 4 different schemas in Oracle database. But I have been instructed to write one piece of logic(may be just one method) of C# code that would execute any of these update stored procedures and  pass their names and input/output parameters dynamically during the run time.Although I have figured out how to dynamically pass the names of the stored procedures but have no clue how to pass different input/output parameters to different stored procedures(using the same C# logic) during the run time.
Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Who came up with that? Basically it's pass the name of the procedure and a collection of parameters (name, value, type?) and then iterate the through the list and add them. Unless there's something stupidly clever going on elsewhere though, it's a really bad idea. How do you 'know' what parameters the proc requires?

Comment: Regarding what parameters the proc requires, I can come to know  by looking at definition of the proc in sql developer. Though I have a big deserialized object from a json file which has all these input/output parameters listed for each proc and corresponding shcema in which that proc falls.

Comment: Hmm you'd have to read in the code for the proc from a schema table (sysprocs?). Regex it for @paramname and type. Then you'd need to cherry pick the values from some sort of collection of 'values that might be used in a proc'. That's not even considering implicit and explicit type casting. Like I said bad idea. Ask me to do this, I'd go back and tell them they hadn't thought it through if I was in polite mode. In tactless mode I'd tell them to stick to their day job....

Comment: Well Tony, Can you please write some kind of small sample code or some link where its getting done the way u r describing it.

Comment: Ha like I said I wouldn't do it. Categorical, point blank, I'm not doing that. No. :) It's a lot of code mate. Need to break it up in to bits. First thing is have a look at the query to get the text of a stored proc from Oracle. Then mine it for params, the values themselves couldn't make a start on without your code. You are already adding params to the procs somewhere, just a question of getting them out of say a dictionary instead of hardcoding.

Comment: Ya I know its a lot of code, just wondering if there is anything on the web that resembles what u said in terms of c# code, Im trying to google hard but to no avail.

Comment: Get text of a stored proc https://community.oracle.com/thread/517948 bit by bit, mate

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: After getting the body of the proc I can mine it for params and then get a corresponding collection of param values from deserialized object and make a dictionary with name value pair and try to give it to the proc in data access code using OracleParameter and then adding them to the OracleCommand. Does that sound ok ...Am I somewhere close to what u r saying?